# How do I fix screen redraw in Windows 10?

Tags: display, graphics-card, windows-10, display-driver

I recently upgraded from Windows 8.1 to Windows 10. After upgrading, some applications do not redraw parts of their screen when needed.

For example, the Chrome address bar does not redraw smoothly when entering text:

[image: Chrome address bar does not redraw smoothly]

I have reinstalled my graphics drivers (AMD Catalyst 15.7.1) but the issue still persists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to have been fixed in the Chrome 45 update.